# long running ajax request preventing page reload

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm using jquery to make an ajax request to a controller method that can potentially take a while to return.  The problem I'm having is that I can't reload the page until the ajax request finishes.. it just hangs until the controller method finishes and then does the page reload.

This is my ajax request.

```
$.ajax({ async:true, type: "POST", url: url, data: senddata, dataType: "xml", success: GetLayerFeaturesCallback });
```

I'm using an AsyncController and waiting 10 seconds to return.

```
    public void GetFeaturesAsync(int layerId, BoundingBox bbox, int maxFeatures = 50)
    {
        AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment();
        Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
        });
        task.ContinueWith(t => {
            AsyncManager.Parameters["element"] = new XElement("TEST");
            AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();
        });
    }

    public XmlActionResult GetFeaturesCompleted(XElement element)
    {
        return new XmlActionResult(element);
    }
```

Why can't I reload the page until that method finishes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be a deadlock in your application or the number of threads or connections(per ip) allowed to process is limited by the webserver.

Can you open ANY other page from another browser or from another computer while the long request is processing?

**edit** sessions in asp.net also causes lock-ups. Only one request at a time may access a session unless you have marked the pages' session as read-only.

Comment: The code is hosted in the local IIS, and there's just one browser instance open hitting it.  I'm not touching the Session.. the code above is the only thing I'm doing.

Comment: Even if there is only one browser hitting it the request will not stop until it is done. IIS does not detect that you canceled the ajax-request and continiues to wait all the 10seconds. Sessions does not have to be touched either to lock up, if you have  EnableSessionState="True" in your <%@ Page declaration the session will be locked.